# Deserialize JSON into Object C#

Tags: c#, json

Hello I am in desperate need of some help. I have a json file, with an array of json objects. I cannot figure out how to deserialize it into a list of this object.

My JSON is in this format in the file - it is thousands of lines long this is just a sample:

```
[{
"Rk": 1,
"Gcar": 467,
"Gtm": 1,
"Date": "Apr 6",
"Tm": "CLE",
"Where": "@",
"Opp": "HOU",
"Rslt": "L0-2",
"Inngs": "CG",
"PA": 4,
"AB": 4,
"R": 0,
"H": 0,
"Doubles": 0,
"Triples": 0,
"HR": 0,
"RBI": 0,
"BB": 0,
"IBB": 0,
"SO": 0,
"HBP": 0,
"SH": 0,
"SF": 0,
"ROE": 0,
"GDP": 0,
"SB": 0,
"CS": 0,
"BA": 0,
"OBP": 0,
"SLG": 0,
"OPS": 0,
"BOP": 2,
"aLI": 0.93,
"WPA": -0.093,
"RE24": -0.64,
"DFSDK": 0,
"DFSFD": -1,
"Pos": "Doubles"
},

{
"Rk": 2,
"Gcar": 468,
"Gtm": 2,
"Date": "Apr 8",
"Tm": "CLE",
"Where": "@",
"Opp": "HOU",
"Rslt": "W2-0",
"Inngs": "CG",
"PA": 4,
"AB": 4,
"R": 0,
"H": 2,
"Doubles": 0,
"Triples": 0,
"HR": 0,
"RBI": 0,
"BB": 0,
"IBB": 0,
"SO": 0,
"HBP": 0,
"SH": 0,
"SF": 0,
"ROE": 0,
"GDP": 0,
"SB": 0,
"CS": 0,
"BA": 0.25,
"OBP": 0.25,
"SLG": 0.25,
"OPS": 0.5,
"BOP": 3,
"aLI": 0.71,
"WPA": -0.008,
"RE24": -0.2,
"DFSDK": 6,
"DFSFD": 1.5,
"Pos": "Doubles"
}
]
```

There is 142 of these objects in the file. I have attempted to Deserialize the object to no avail. At this point I'm ready to start from scratch and I'm just looking for some direction to get this data into a usable object?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or what *specifically* is going wrong?

Comment: post your code along with the error you are getting

Comment: It says that it does not recognize it as json whenever i try to make it into a JObject. So I've proceeded to make a class with all the fields from the Json object and I would like to know the best method to getting the data into a list of this type?

Comment: It's an JsonArray? Which library are you using?

Comment: string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
JArray myObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

Comment: ok now i finally got it stored in myObj as above...how do i map that to an object with the same data fields now?

Comment: Why dont you create a class with the Collection variable of your json object? I am assuming you are using Newtonsoft Json.

Comment: i have created a class with a list of type <player> which contains all the fields from my json data. how can i put a JArray into that list?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio 2013, 2015 to create your model classes from a json, I did it and I parsed the JSON fine.
To use this feature, you must have JSON/XML in your clipboard, put your cursor  inside a .cs file and then use the option **Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON AS Classes**

[image: Paste Special JSON as classes]

Look the code that was generated:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int Rk { get; set; }
    public int Gcar { get; set; }
    public int Gtm { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Tm { get; set; }
    public string Where { get; set; }
    public string Opp { get; set; }
    public string Rslt { get; set; }
    public string Inngs { get; set; }
    public int PA { get; set; }
    public int AB { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
    public int H { get; set; }
    public int Doubles { get; set; }
    public int Triples { get; set; }
    public int HR { get; set; }
    public int RBI { get; set; }
    public int BB { get; set; }
    public int IBB { get; set; }
    public int SO { get; set; }
    public int HBP { get; set; }
    public int SH { get; set; }
    public int SF { get; set; }
    public int ROE { get; set; }
    public int GDP { get; set; }
    public int SB { get; set; }
    public int CS { get; set; }
    public float BA { get; set; }
    public float OBP { get; set; }
    public float SLG { get; set; }
    public float OPS { get; set; }
    public int BOP { get; set; }
    public float aLI { get; set; }
    public float WPA { get; set; }
    public float RE24 { get; set; }
    public int DFSDK { get; set; }
    public float DFSFD { get; set; }
    public string Pos { get; set; }
}
```

In runtime to deserialize JSON into this object created from Visual Studio, you can use Newtonsoft.Json, you can install this using nuget with the following command:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Now you can deserialized it, using the gerenric method **DeserializedObject** from the static class **JsconCovert**, like that:

```
Rootobject object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

Comment: GREAT TIP! a lot of good answers but this is life changing right here!

Comment: Nice Tip. You did my day

Comment: Great ..!! Thanks for new way to create json to c# object. Truly awesome way.

Comment: Lucky i read this, i normally always create them manually -.---

Comment: so easy -thank you so much!!

Answer (score 8):

This is very simple to do using Newtonsoft.JSON and there is a page in the documentation covering [how to deserialize an object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm).

Taken from the documentation page:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

// code to deserialize from JSON string to a typed object
string json = @"{
    'Email': 'james@example.com',
    'Active': true,
    'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
    'Roles': [
        'User',
        'Admin'
    ]
";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
// james@example.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Newtonsoft provide a way to do it.

```
CustomClass myClassWithCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomClass>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"path"))
{
     string jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
     JArray myObj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

     var player = new Player();
     player.statsBase = myObj.ToObject<List<StatsBase>>();
}
```

This is how i finally accomplished it. I'm not sure if the above answers will work for multiple JSON objects in the same file.

Comment: Try my answer, its a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

Add this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/7.0.1 on your project.

This is the link for my solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eqJXTy

And then:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> obj =
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.
        DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(jsonString);

foreach(Dictionary<string, string> lst in obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--NewObject--");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Rk: {0} Gcar: {1}", lst["Rk"], lst["Gcar"]));
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> item in lst)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Key: {0} Value: {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
    }
}
```

Happy to help you!