# Problems with deserializing Json from RIOT Api in C# UWP

Tags: c#, json

I am new to stack overflow and I am a beginner programmer.
I wanted to make an application that is about League of Legends but I have a problem. I just can't figure out how to deserialize the json into an object.

This is what I've tried

```
public class LOL
{
    public User user { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

These are the classes I created using the website http://json2csharp.com/ .

I've just changed the name of these classes to something I like

This is my other class where I call the API

```
public class LOLFacade
{
    private const string APIKey = "secret :D";

    public async static Task<LOL> ConnectToRiot(string user)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        string riotURL = String.Format("https://eune.api.pvp.net/api/lol/eune/v1.4/summoner/by-name/{0}?api_key={1}", user, APIKey);
        var response = await http.GetAsync(riotURL);

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LOL>(result);
    }
}
```

This is the place I use the API

```
private async void GetUserInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LOL user = await LOLFacade.ConnectToRiot("gigaxel");
     string name = user.user.name;
     int level = user.user.summonerLevel;

     InfoTextBlock.Text = name + " is level " + level;
}
```

And I always get this error when I execute my code :( :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the Json:

> {"gigaxel": {
>      "id": 36588106,
>      "name": "Gigaxel",
>      "profileIconId": 713,
>      "revisionDate": 1451494377000,
>      "summonerLevel": 30
>   }}

Please if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. I just started and I think that I made a lot of mistakes in this code but if you could help me I would really appreciate it :D

Comment: In which line of code you get this error.

Comment: this is very easy exception to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LOL model doesn't match with JSON that you received.

Look my answer in this question: [Deserialize JSON into Object C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302845/deserialize-json-into-object-c-sharp/34303130#34303130)

The correct model is that

```
public class LOL
{
    public Gigaxel gigaxel { get; set; }
}

public class Gigaxel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer made a lot of things clear to me :D

Comment: Thank you again and I wish you a happy new year as well :D

Answer (score 1):

try the following class instead of your `LOL` class

```
public class LOL
{
   public User gigaxel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issues pointed by the other users, your error is due to the fact that you are trying to deserialize the JSON into an object that you never instantiated. You have to create the object before deserializing:

```
LOL LOLObj = new LOL { user = new User() };
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LOLObj>(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It fixed my problem :D