# json.net, how do I deserialize json object from relative path or actual json object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

can someone tell me how to deserialize a json object using either a path to another json file or a json object?

I am trying to make a game where its entirely constructed of config files.

basically I would take either these two...

```
{
    "LevelConfig" : {
        "SkillGain" : 0.01,
        "MagicGain" : 0.01,
        "XpScale"   : 50.0,
        "HpScale"   : 0.01,
        "MpScale"   : 0.01
    }
}

or 

{
    "LevelConfig" : "../Level.level" (only returns json object if file exists else it tries to return string)
}
```

and convert them into these

```
public class JLevel
{
    public float SkillGain { get; set; }
    public float MagicGain { get; set; }
    public float XpScale   { get; set; }
    public float HpScale   { get; set; }
    public float MpScale   { get; set; }
}

public class JEntity
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int    Hp   { get; set; }
        public int    Mp   { get; set; }
        public int    Xp   { get; set; }

        public JLevel   LevelConfig   { get; set; }
        public JColor   ColorConfig   { get; set; }
        public JPhysics PhysicsConfig { get; set; }
}

class Entity
{
        public Entity Load(string filename)
        {
                return ???;
        }
        public void Save(string filename)
        {
                ???;
        }
}
```

now I know I can just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` but that doesn't check for json paths.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into Object C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302845/deserialize-json-into-object-c-sharp)

Comment: its not about deserializing json its how to deserialize it in a way that it accepts string paths as objects.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText`  is probably what you are after.

Comment: this would work but I am aiming more towards a custom deserializer. that method would require me to search for it

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a class for this Json Object

> The name of class should be the same as Object name in JSON

```
{
    "LevelConfig" : {
        "SkillGain" : 0.01,
        "MagicGain" : 0.01,
        "XpScale"   : 50.0,
        "HpScale"   : 0.01,
        "MpScale"   : 0.01
    }
}



public class LevelConfig
    {
        public double SkillGain { get; set; }
        public double MagicGain { get; set; }
        public double XpScale { get; set; }
        public double HpScale { get; set; }
        public double MpScale { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public LevelConfig LevelConfig { get; set; }
    }
```

then you need to desalinize it using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(Json);
```

> Json should be a string. If its an Object the you need to use this on

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Json));
```

Comment: I already know this but I don't think this works if the key "LevelConfig" is a path to another json file

Comment: your Json object is nested inside the object.. you need to create a class in another class.

Comment: I did its called JLevel

Comment: I have modified the answer

Comment: oh ok I see what you mean by "The name of class should be the same as Object name in JSON". but I still don't understand how "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Json));" fixes my problem.

Comment: **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject** use string as input. and i guess that you might have Object value, that's why i modified my answer to first convert the object into String then Deserialize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189750/discussion-between-shadowblitz16-and-zulqarnain-jalil).

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "{ LevelConfig : \"level.json\"}";
        var levelConfigs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LevelConfigs>(str);
        var fileTxt = GetFileText(levelConfigs.LevelConfig);
        JLevel level = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JLevel>(fileTxt);
        Console.WriteLine(level.HpScale);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static string GetFileText(string jsonFile)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
    }
}

public class LevelConfigs
{
    public string LevelConfig { get; set; }
}

public class JLevel
{
    public float SkillGain { get; set; }
    public float MagicGain { get; set; }
    public float XpScale { get; set; }
    public float HpScale { get; set; }
    public float MpScale { get; set; }
}

public class JEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Hp { get; set; }
    public int Mp { get; set; }
    public int Xp { get; set; }

    public JLevel LevelConfig { get; set; }

}
```

you can change your implementation of GetFileText for your needs

Comment: i there a way to do this so I can simply call a deserialize function and deserialize the whole object including the nested LevelConfig?

Comment: you need to create a custom jsonconverter for your needs

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: ya but I'm not sure how to handle this. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm 's example isn't very good on what I need to do.

Comment: is there a way to execute code on all string types in the json object?