# How deserialize json object to c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want deserialize this object from JSON:

```
{"domain":"google.com","data":{"available":true,"expiration":null,"registrant_email":null}}
```

I use this code:

```
public class Data
{
    public string available { get; set; }
}

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(finishResponse);
Console.WriteLine(data.available);
```

please help me for it!

Comment: [Knock yourself out...](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp)

Comment: Your root data model does not match your JSON.  To generate a correct data model automatically, see [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674/3744182).

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302845/deserialize-json-into-object-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class doesn't match the JSON... Here are a couple of classes that do match the JSON:

```
public class MyJson
{
    [JsonProperty("domain")]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("available")]
    public bool Available { get; set; }

    // This should probably be a nullable DateTime
    [JsonProperty("expiration")]
    public object Expiration { get; set; } 

    // And this should probably be a string...
    [JsonProperty("registrant_email")]
    public object RegistrantEmail { get; set; }
}
```

[I've generated them online directly from your JSON.](https://app.quicktype.io?share=JXQKRpNUZtpojkvGya54)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this change. This way your C# classes will match the JSON object your are receiving. You should of course extend the `Data` class to include the rest of the json fields if they are of interest to you.

```
  public class Response
  {
      [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
      public string Domain { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
      public Data Data { get; set; }
  }
```

You will notice that I added the required to `AllowNull` for `Expiration`+`RegistrantEmail` and the `Data` property to `Always`. If you send null for `Data` the deserialization will fail.

```
  public partial class Data
  {
      [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Default)]
      public bool Available { get; set; }

      [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
      public object Expiration { get; set; } 


      [JsonProperty("registrant_email" ,Required = Required.AllowNull)]
      public object RegistrantEmail { get; set; }
  }

  var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(finishResponse);
  Console.WriteLine(response.Data.available);
```

This answer also considers some of the fields in your serialized json string may be null and thus won't throw exception if that's the case.