# How can i access fields of anonymous typed JArray in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, types, anonymous-types

```
string sampleString = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"status\":302},{\"id\":\"2\",\"status\":302},{\"id\":\"3\",\"status\":302},{\"id\":\"4\",\"status\":302}]";     
JArray json = JArray.Parse(sampleString );
TempValue t;
foreach(JObject obj in json)
{
t = new TempValue {
id =//id of json,
status=//state of json
};
}
```

i want to access value of json anonymous objec to assign to t object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON into Object C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302845/deserialize-json-into-object-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to work with a typed object to avoid typing mistakes. In this case create a class with the structure of the json string like so:

```
   public class StatusObj
   {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public int status { get; set; }
   }
```

The deserialize the json string to list of your class like so:

```
List<StatusObj> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StatusObj>>(sampleString);
```

And then you can loop through the list like so:

```
foreach (var item in obj)
 {
   var id = item.id;
   var status = item.status;
 }
```

The whole code look like this:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sampleString = "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"status\":302},{\"id\":\"2\",\"status\":302},{\"id\":\"3\",\"status\":302},{\"id\":\"4\",\"status\":302}]";

        List<StatusObj> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StatusObj>>(sampleString);

        foreach (var item in obj)
        {
            var id = item.id;
            var status = item.status;
        }

    }
}

public class StatusObj
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
}
```

NB. Newtonsoft.Json package needed to be installed. You can also convert any json to class [here](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: "*if you can up mark the question, it will more beneficial to further viewers*" - this was kind of funny

Answer (score 0):

By the *indexer*

```
foreach(JObject obj in json)
{
    t = new TempValue {
    id = obj["id"].ToString() ,
      ...   
};
```

---

[Object.Item Property (String)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm)

> Gets or sets the JToken with the specified property name.