# MS Graph OneNote Get Section displayName

Tags: c#, onenote-api

I'm trying to get the "displayName" of the parentNotebook of a Section in OneNote using MS Graph.  I can get the Id and Body, using the following code.

public static readonly string apiSectionRoute = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections";

```
 HttpRequestMessage createMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiSectionRoute);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(createMessage);

            var apiBaseResponse = new List<ApiBaseResponse>();
            string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK
                /* GET Notebooks calls always return 200-OK upon success */)
            {
                var content = JObject.Parse(body);
                apiBaseResponse = new List<ApiBaseResponse>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GenericEntityResponse>>(content["value"].ToString()));
            }
            if (apiBaseResponse.Count == 0)
            {
                apiBaseResponse.Add(new ApiBaseResponse());
            }

            // Extract the correlation id.  Apps should log this if they want to collect the data to diagnose failures with Microsoft support
            IEnumerable<string> correlationValues;
            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-CorrelationId", out correlationValues))
            {
                apiBaseResponse[0].CorrelationId = correlationValues.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            apiBaseResponse[0].StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            apiBaseResponse[0].Body = body;

            ///TTD this finds the first one and just happens to be for CWON
            ///

            Globals.CurrentSectionsId=apiBaseResponse[0].Id.ToString();
```

But I can't find any sample code that gives me the "displayName" ?

Here is the APIBaseResponse class:

```
 public class ApiBaseResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// All OneNote API reponses return a meaningful Http status code
    /// Typical pattern for Http status codes are used:
    /// 1 1xx Informational
    /// 2 2xx Success. e.g. 200-OK for GETs, 201 -Created for POSTs
    /// 3 3xx Redirection
    /// 4 4xx Client Error e.g. 400-Bad Request
    /// 5 5xx Server Error e.g. 500-Internal Server Error
    /// </summary>
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Per call identifier that can be logged to diagnose issues with Microsoft support
    /// CorrelationId is included in all Response Headers
    /// </summary>
    public string CorrelationId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Body of the OneNote API response represented as a string.
    /// For error cases, this will typically include an error json intended for developers, not for end users.
    /// For success cases, depending on the type API call/HTTP verb this may or may not include a json value
    /// </summary>
    public string Body { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// URLs to launch OneNote rich client/web app
    /// </summary>
    public Links Links { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unique identifier of the object
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }


}

public class Links
{
    /// <summary>
    /// URL to launch OneNote rich client
    /// </summary>
    public HrefUrl OneNoteClientUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// URL to launch OneNote web experience
    /// </summary>
    public HrefUrl OneNoteWebUrl { get; set; }
}

public class HrefUrl
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
}

public class GenericEntityResponse : ApiBaseResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the entity
    /// </summary>
    public string displayName;

    /// <summary>
    /// Self link to the given entity
    /// </summary>
    public string Self { get; set; }

 
    public List<GenericEntityResponse> Sections { get; set; }

    public List<GenericEntityResponse> SectionGroups { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name: " + displayName + ", Id: " + Id;
    }
}

public class NBookSections
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class CaroItem
{
    public string CItem
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer (yet again), so I found a way to get the parent notebook's displayName.

Basically the `content` object that's being returned is a collection of what your request returns.

If you wanted an easy way to create a class to represent your JSON response (including getting the parentNotebook), here's a handy link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34303130/9437098

By following the above method, I created a class based on the JSON response, renamed the "Value" class that it created as "Section". I then went like so:

```
var content = JObject.Parse(body);

List<Section> sections = new();

foreach (JToken t in content["value"])
{
   sections.Add(t.ToObject<Section>());
}
```

As you can see, doing it this way will give you basically a list of the sections returned with corresponding objects / properties:
[image: Here's a screencap (I set a breakpoint right afterwards to check the value of parentDisplayName): [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

Here's a copy of the class I created for the Section:

```
    public class Section
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDateTime { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public bool isDefault { get; set; }
        public string pagesUrl { get; set; }
        public Createdby createdBy { get; set; }
        public Lastmodifiedby lastModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Links links { get; set; }
        public string parentNotebookodatacontext { get; set; }
        public Parentnotebook parentNotebook { get; set; }
        public string parentSectionGroupodatacontext { get; set; }
        public object parentSectionGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class Createdby
    {
        public User user { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public object id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Lastmodifiedby
    {
        public User1 user { get; set; }
    }

    public class User1
    {
        public object id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Onenoteclienturl oneNoteClientUrl { get; set; }
        public Onenoteweburl oneNoteWebUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Onenoteclienturl
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Onenoteweburl
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parentnotebook
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string self { get; set; }
    }
```

Hopefully this helps a little!

Comment: It does not appear in the ApiBaseResponse, I've tried to add the property to the object but have been unseuccessful.

Comment: @TreyBalut, would you be able to share what the ApiBaseResponse looks like? I'm not familiar with that class (I can't seem to find any documentation for it). I'd like to try it out myself to see if I can't figure something out for it.

Comment: Rrrrrrr,  I've edited the original post and include the ApiBaseResponse class. Hope this helps.

Comment: @TreyBalut I updated my answer with a way of getting to the displayName of the parentNotebook, let me know if it helps at all!

Comment: Rrrr,  Thanks, I tried your changes and it exposed all of the values that I was trying to capture/identify.  Gracias

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!